# How to generate number by inversion method

Tags: matlab, statistics

I have a algorithm that count the number in a range such as

1. Compute F(x), x from 0 to n
2. Generate a uniform number z
   `If(F(x)<=z<F(x+1))` then `k=x`

In which, F(x) is Cumulative distribution function that compute by [Binomial_distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

For example, F(x)=0.12, 0.2, 0.5, ..1.

z=0.3 then return k=1

I implement it by matlab. However, it returned wrong result. Could you see my implementation help me? If it wrong, please give me the solution

```
clear all;
number_generated = 500000;
p=0.3;
n=20
%% Compute F(x): x=0..20
sum_F=0;
for x=0:n
        sum_F=sum_F+nchoosek(n,x)*p^x*(1-p)^(n-x);
        F(x+1)=sum_F;% matlab index from 1
end    
k_arr=[]; %% Store k
for num=1:number_generated
    %% Generate z_i uniform in the interval (0,1)
    z=rand();
    %% Find k such that F(x)<=z<F(x+1)
    for i=1:length(F)-1 
        if(F(i)<=z & z<F(i+1))
            k=i-1; % matlab index from 1
            break;
        end
    end    
    k_arr=[k_arr k]; %% Record k in array
end
```

Comment: a) What result do you get? b) Why is it 'wrong result'? and c) What would you expect the 'correct' result to be?

Comment: My expected result must be follow Binomial distribution. I run it and draw cdf. It does not look like the distribution. So I sure that it was wrong. My expected correct is from the above algorithm, please check my implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is essentially correct, but you forgot the first interval between `0` and `F(1)`.

Other comments on your code:

1. Always pre-allocate arrays
2. Use `&&` instead of `&` in logical conditions.

Updated code:

```
clear all;
close all;
number_generated = 500000;
p=0.3;
n=20;
% Preallocate F array.
F = NaN(n + 2, 1);
% Set first value to 0
F(1) = 0;
% Save binomial distribution for plotting.
bin = zeros(n + 1, 1);
% Compute F(x): x=0..20
sum_F=0;
for x=0:n
    % Save binomial distribution for plotting.
    bin(x + 1) = nchoosek(n,x)*p^x*(1-p)^(n-x);
    sum_F=sum_F+bin(x + 1);
    % This is now x+2 because F(1) is 0.
    F(x+2)=sum_F;% matlab index from 1
end
% Preallocate k_arr array.
k_arr=NaN(number_generated, 1); %% Store k
for num=1:number_generated
    % Generate z_i uniform in the interval (0,1)
    z=rand();
    % Find k such that F(x)<=z<F(x+1)
    for i=1:length(F)-1 
        if(z >= F(i) && z < F(i+1))
            k=i-1; % matlab index from 1
            break;
        end
    end    
    k_arr(num) = k; % Record k in array
end

% Plot expected result
figure
stairs((0:n) - 0.5, bin);
xlim([-1 20]);

% Plot sampled result
figure
histogram(k_arr);
xlim([-1 20]);
```

Expected distribution:

[image]

Sampled distribution:

[image]

Comment: @user3051460 I'm pleased that it's working for you. Incidentally you can replace the final loop inside `for num=1:number_generated` with simply `k_arr(num) = find(F < rand(), 1, 'last') - 1;`